# Can you have a scope which checks from absence?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scopes

I have an `Invites` table in my database and when i'm perform a task as a user I want to pass an `Event`.id to a scope `User.not_invited_to(event)`

How do I build this scope to check if the user ID is NOT in there?

```
class User
  has_many :invites, :foreign_key => 'participant_id'
  ...
end

class Invite
  belongs_to :participant, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "participant_id"
  ...
end
```

Comment: I can do it this way. `scope :not_invited, lambda{|event|
    where("id not in (?)", event.invites.collect{|i| i.participant_id }.join(','))
  }`

Comment: can you give more information about your schema ? there may be a more efficient way to do this

Comment: in the previous comment it should say `i.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `event.invite_ids`:

```
scope :not_invited, lambda { |event| where("id not in (?)", event.invite_ids) }
```

Comment: I did not realise this, i've being using collect a lot. so would .._ids do that for me?

Comment: Yes, `*_ids` does that for you. It's [one of the things added](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference) to your ActiveRecord object when it has a `has_many` association to an other model.